# Why does When.js promise.then skip a function?

Tags: javascript, promise, when-js

Can someone explain why this prints in reverse order?

Code:

```
when('test')
  .then(function() {console.log('should be first');})
  .then(console.log('should be second'));
```

Output:

```
should be second
should be first
```

PS: I am using when.js version: when@3.4.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're immediately executing the second `console.log`, and passing the return value to `then`. You need to pass functions to `then`.

You've effectively done this:

```
var x = console.log('should be second')

when('test')
  .then(function () { console.log('should be first'); })
  .then(x);
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning - that /A+ Promise libraries like WhenJS guarantee that this is _always_ the order things happen. in some promise implementations you do not have that guarantee (that code in `.then` is always run async)